# Why is the div not displayed near the link?

Tags: html, css

I wonder why is the `<div class="content-0">` not displayed near the related anchors but displayed near the first anchor? This behavior is  not happening for `<div class="content-1">` even though they are using the same CSS codes. When I hover the anchor called `Örnek Bilgileri` which opens after hovered the anchor called `Ekle`, a `div` is displayed near this anchor. The `<div class="content-0">` should have behaved like this too.

Can you help me to see what I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sidenav">
        <div class="item-0">
            <a class="item-0-link" href="#">Dosya</a>
            <div class="content-0">
                <a class="content-link" href="#">Aç</a>
                <a class="content-link" href="#">Kapat</a>
                <a class="content-link" href="#">Kaydet</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-0">
            <a class="item-0-link" href="#">Ekle</a>
            <div class="content-0">
                <a class="content-link" href="#">Derinlik Bilgisi</a>
                <a class="content-link" href="#">Muhafaza Borusu Bilgisi</a>
                <a class="content-link" href="#">Proje Ve Şirket Bilgileri</a>
                <a class="content-link" href="#">Litoloji Bilgileri</a>
                <div class="item-1">
                    <a class="item-1-link" href="#">Örnek Bilgileri</a>
                    <div class="content-1">
                        <a class="content-link" href="#">rc</a>
                        <a class="content-link" href="#">spt</a>
                        <a class="content-link" href="#">ud</a>
                        <a class="content-link" href="#">pr</a>
                        <a class="content-link" href="#">pd</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-0">
            <a class="item-0-link" href="#">Tuval</a>
            <div class="content-0">
                <a class="content-link" href="#">Görüntüle</a>
                <a class="content-link" href="#">Dışa Aktar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-0">
            <a class="item-0-link" href="#">Ayarlar</a>
            <div class="content-0">
                <a class="content-link" href="#">Dil</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-0">
            <a class="item-0-link">Yardım</a>
            <div class="content-0">
                <a class="content-link" href="#">Hakkında</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <style>
        .sidenav {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: #fff;
            opacity: 0.7;
            display: block;
            float: left;
        }

        .item-0 {
            display: block;
        }

        .content-0, .content-1 {
            display: none;
            background-color: #fff;
            position: absolute;
            float: left;
        }

        .content-link {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: green;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 200px;
        }

        .item-0-link, .item-1-link {
            padding: 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: green;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: white;
            float: left;
        }

        .item-1-link {
            width: 200px;
        }

        .sidenav a:hover {
            color: #000;
            background-color: green;
        }

        .item-0:hover .content-0, .item-1:hover .content-1 {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .item-0:hover .item-0-link, .item-1:hover .item-1-link {
            color: #000;
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The float is not really a much better way, for positioning things. Actually all `.item-0` elements (parent element for `.item-0-link` element) were aligned at the top, because of being floated.

If you would inspect, you will find that, the content of floated element is not producing height for parent, i.e. `.item-0`. Same goes for `.item-1`, but it is not direct child of `.item-0`, that is why, it worked perfectly for it.

Now there are two ways, to resolve this problem :

(1) **With just CSS :** Remove all the float properties, and use positioning.

Here is a working demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="sidenav">
    <div class="item-0">
      <a class="item-0-link" href="#">Dosya</a>
      <div class="content-0">
        <a class="content-link" href="#">Aç</a>
        <a class="content-link" href="#">Kapat</a>
        <a class="content-link" href="#">Kaydet</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-0">
      <a class="item-0-link" href="#">Ekle</a>
      <div class="content-0">
        <a class="content-link" href="#">Derinlik Bilgisi</a>
        <a class="content-link" href="#">Muhafaza Borusu Bilgisi</a>
        <a class="content-link" href="#">Proje Ve Şirket Bilgileri</a>
        <a class="content-link" href="#">Litoloji Bilgileri</a>
        <div class="item-1">
          <a class="item-1-link" href="#">Örnek Bilgileri</a>
          <div class="content-1">
            <a class="content-link" href="#">rc</a>
            <a class="content-link" href="#">spt</a>
            <a class="content-link" href="#">ud</a>
            <a class="content-link" href="#">pr</a>
            <a class="content-link" href="#">pd</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-0">
      <a class="item-0-link" href="#">Tuval</a>
      <div class="content-0">
        <a class="content-link" href="#">Görüntüle</a>
        <a class="content-link" href="#">Dışa Aktar</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-0">
      <a class="item-0-link" href="#">Ayarlar</a>
      <div class="content-0">
        <a class="content-link" href="#">Dil</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-0">
      <a class="item-0-link">Yardım</a>
      <div class="content-0">
        <a class="content-link" href="#">Hakkında</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <style>
    .sidenav {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: #fff;
      opacity: 0.7;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .item-0 {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .item-0, .item-1 {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .content-0,
    .content-1 {
      display: none;
      background-color: #fff;
      position: absolute;
      left: calc(100% + 20px);
      top: 0;
    }
    
    .content-link {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: green;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 200px;
    }
    
    .item-0-link,
    .item-1-link {
      padding: 10px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: green;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: white;
    }
    
    .item-1-link {
      width: 200px;
    }
    
    .sidenav a:hover {
      color: #000;
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    .item-0:hover .content-0,
    .item-1:hover .content-1 {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .item-0:hover .item-0-link,
    .item-1:hover .item-1-link {
      color: #000;
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

(2) **By changing HTML structure :** For that, append an empty `span` element to every floated element and add some CSS to it. The CSS will be :

```css
clear: both;
```

NOTE : You would have to append it in every single floated element.

Comment: Thank you, I will change the necessary parts.